# Нумерация (Pagination) на странице со всеми комментариями сайта

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, комментарии

Добрый вечер!

Есть проблема с пагинацией комментариев на WP.

Имеем страницу на которой должны выводиться все комментарии сайта (вообще все утвержденные комментарии со всех страниц).

Код следующий:

```
<ol class="comment-list">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'style'       => 'ol',
        'short_ping'  => true,
        'avatar_size' => 34,
        'reverse_top_level' => false,
    );
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'status' => 'approve', //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
    ));
    wp_list_comments($args, $comments);
    ?>
</ol><!-- .comment-list -->

<?php paginate_comments_links(); ?>
```

Просто выводим все комментарии со статусом approve и выводим пагинацию (В админке настроена так, чтобы выводилось 5 комментариев на страницу).

Одно уточнение: на этой странице так же есть форма оставления комментария.

И вот тут начинается веселье: Комментарии выводятся как и должно - все и отовсюду и по 5 штук на страницу. Вот только пагинация учитывает только те комментарии, которые были сделаны конкретно на этой странице.

При общем кол-ве комментариев на сайте - 50, на этой странице сделано 8 комментариев и paginate_comments_links(); выводит 2 страницы ровно под эти 8.

Я немного дополнил вызов пагинации для комментариев:

```
<?php
$page = get_query_var('cpage');
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
$all_approved = $comments_count->approved;
$max_page = get_comment_pages_count($all_approved);
$cmlink = array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => null,
    'total' => $max_page,
    'current' => $page,
    'echo' => true,
    'add_fragment' => '#comments'
);
paginate_comments_links($cmlink);
?>
```

После этого кол-во страниц в пагинации стало верным, но на страницах выше второй (3,4,5...) нет вывода ни комментариев, ни формы, ни самой пагинации.

Помогите. Что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 2):

Все, разобрался.
В цикле вывода постов было условие

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
//code
<?php endif ?>
```

И применялось оно к конкретной странице. Потому и выводило комментарии только для данной страницы.

Сорри за невнимательность.